# Eclipse ADT and Debugger does not work after Android Studio Install

Tags: android, eclipse

I use Eclipse(version is Juno of pleiades eclipse) and develop Android application.

Today I install Android Studio, but Eclipse ADT does not works(do not run).
After Eclipse reinstall ADT and reset SDK but does not work.
And Run Configuration(Toolbar>Run>(N) sorry, my eclipse in Japanese...) does not work.

Logs.

```
[2015-02-08 17:48:13 - SwitchUserSample] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-02-08 17:48:13 - SwitchUserSample] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-02-08 17:48:13 - SwitchUserSample] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-02-08 17:48:13 - SwitchUserSample] Versions found are:
[2015-02-08 17:48:13 - SwitchUserSample] Path: D:\Program Files\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-02-08 17:48:13 - SwitchUserSample]    Length: 393154
[2015-02-08 17:48:13 - SwitchUserSample]    SHA-1: 307c1cc532eabbf1d135b43e5c983c9da700449d
[2015-02-08 17:48:13 - SwitchUserSample] Path: D:\Program Files\facebook-android-sdk-3.21.1\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-02-08 17:48:13 - SwitchUserSample]    Length: 758727
[2015-02-08 17:48:13 - SwitchUserSample]    SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
```

Omission

```
[2015-02-08 17:49:19 - PhotoSelectionActivity] D:\Program Files\Laevatein-master\laevatein\src\main\res\layout\l_activity_preview.xml:2: Error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').
```

I do not understand why does not move.
How to repair?

Comment: 3 developers in our company are having the same problem, have you found the solution?